# Magento static block javascript variable

Tags: javascript, magento, variables

I have been studying Magento for a week and I stuck at Magento static blocks. I were writing some code in static block content. With lines:

```
"Testing Magento variables {{config path="general/store_information/name"}}"
```

im getting my store name perfectly. My problem is that I have tried several times to assign that variable to javascript **greeting** variable but always failed. Maybe someone could help me what I should write instead of **??????**. I will use that for if else sentence.

```
<html>
<body>

"Testing Magento variables {{config path="general/store_information/name"}}"

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() 
   {
      var greeting = ??????????;

   }
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to assign the store name to a variable;

```
var greeting = '{{config path="general/store_information/name"}}';
```

You can also create your own custom variable in admin: system > custom variables (from top menu), and call those in cms blocks or pages with;

```
{{customvar code="my_custom_var"}}
```

By the way, you shouldn't be adding the html and body tags to cms blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but try wrapping the text ...

"Testing Magento variables {{config path="general/store_information/name"}}"

as ...

```
"Testing Magento variables <span id="name">{{config path="general/store_information/name"}}</span>"
```

then you can reference it in the function as ...

```
var greeting = document.getElementById("name").innerText;
```